# Urllib2 - Django - Broken Pipe

Tags: python, django, urllib2

I am new to Django and I am experiencing some troubles posting data to a django webapp.

On the django side I have a form (backed by couchdb - couchdbkit django ext.).
On the client side I post data with urllib2, in bulk (going through a list of data to post one by one)

```
data = urllib.urlencode(param)
req = urllib2.Request(OBJECT_SERVICE_URL + '/objects/create/', data)
req.add_header('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
res.close()
```

After one record (one post passing), it get the message below, running again the next line passes and I have again this message :

```
       res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
  urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

The server says :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 420, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 318, in write
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59571)
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
----------------------------------------
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 309, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 570, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 618, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 661, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I must state that I am working on the embedded django development web server...

And here is the output of the test :

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_create_object (objects.tests.ObjectAppTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/patrick/workspace_py/objects/tests.py", line 21, in test_create_object
    rs = c.post('/objects/create/', param)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 455, in post
    response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 256, in post
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 387, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 84, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/home/patrick/workspace_py/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/coffin/views/defaults.py", line 34, in server_error
    content = render_to_string(template_name, Context({}))
  File "/home/patrick/workspace_py/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/coffin/template/loader.py", line 50, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name)
  File "/home/patrick/workspace_py/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/coffin/template/loader.py", line 24, in get_template
    return env.get_template(template_name)
  File "/home/patrick/workspace_py/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 719, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/patrick/workspace_py/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 693, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/home/patrick/workspace_py/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/home/patrick/workspace_py/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 377, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: 500.html

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone know how to fix ?

Patrick

Comment: The problem seem to be in your server code, not the client. In fact the client just says that the server returned an error code. You might want to try/catch your server code to see the exception on that side.

Comment: Or use a unit test, where you can do with the test client (`self.client` in a test case) what you would do with urllib.

Comment: I added the server logs. I'll write a test.

Comment: These stacktraces look like a client that left before reading the content that was sent to him. If you did not raise the default log level you should only see a GET /objects/create/ 500 in your console. You hsould really add a try/catch in your django view with something like import traceback traceback.print_exc(). Or try the unit test :)

Comment: I added the test output in the meantime, I'll add the try / catch block you suggest...

Comment: I added the try / catch in the view and found the problem.Thank you JC !

Comment: Seems like you messed up settings.py. Django doesn't find the 500.html template. Set DEBUG=True to get more informative feedback. Do you use networking within the Django app? Test that separate from the app.

Comment: Mmmm, I don't use networking, I have DEBUG=True the problem was really a little bug in the view side ... which ended in this confusing message. Thanks a lot !

Comment: How big is your data? It could be you are running against the buffer size of the remote server. You should use multipart post on big data chunks.

Answer (score -1):

Some times I found weird errors and quick connection resets using development server (like in your log). If your application is about http, REST and webservices you should use Apache or Gunicorn so you feel a more realistic enviroment while developing.

Comment: Does it mean the embedded server is unstable ?

Comment: Cherrypy is stable enough for development, and is intended for that. Stick with it until your errors are resolved.

Comment: Django doesn't use cherrypy as development server.

Comment: @patoch let's say it doesn't cover all scenarios. if your architecture is big enough you should make early tests in more similar to production enviroments, and also don't forget to run once in a coding session your app with DEBUG=False.